# Spring security custom exception handler with preauth

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to configure some custom exception handling with Spring Security 3.1.2. I tried following the examples I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094449/spring-exception-handler-to-not-handle-certain-types-of-exception) and [here](http://rockycode.com/blog/custom-exception-handling-accessdeniedexception/), but neither works. I'm new to Spring Security, and I'm wondering if this might have something to do with the fact that I'm using a preauth filter. I'm throwing my custom exceptions from within the loadUserDetails() method of my AuthenticationUserDetailsService implementation.

```
public class AuthServiceImpl implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<Authentication> {
  @Autowired
  private AuthDao authDao;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserDetails(Authentication auth) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Request req = (Request) auth.getPrincipal();

    //get user details
    User u = authDao.loadUser(req.getSessionId());

    //check user rights for requested action
    if(!u.getRights().contains(req.getAction()){
      throw new CustomAuthException("User does not have permission to perform this action");
    }

    return u;
  }
}
```

When the exception is thrown I just get the normal Tomcat 500 page with the exception details. For whatever reason my custom exceptions are not getting handled at all. I even added some println()s in the custom handler, and it's not even being called.

I'm starting to wonder if this method is somehow excluded from Spring's exception handling. I can provide more code examples if needed, but at this point I'm not sure what would be relevant to share.

Comment: can you say what's not working exactly?

Comment: @TheZuck I've edited my question to be more specific with my issue

Answer (score 2):

You use **SimpleMappingExceptionResolver**. It is a Spring MVC component. So when you have some exception during execution of some controller then DispatcherServlet will call SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.
The problem is that your AuthenticationUserDetailsService implementation is used only during login action. And this action is **processed by Spring Security filter directly (Spring MVC is not used)**. Request does not reach DispatcherServlet and SimpleMappingExceptionResolver will never be called for this case.

Comment: Okay, so is there a Spring Security version of the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver? I'm trying to define error pages for certain kinds of authorization failures.

Comment: I think there is no way to do it in Spring Security. Look into **loadUserByUsername** contract. This method can throw only UsernameNotFoundException. There is no extension point to add permission checking during authentication. More important question is why do you want to check permissions during authentication?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other way to do action level security checks when using an external authentication system. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485122/spring-security-authorization-via-get-parameters. If there's another way to do this, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I am not sure for your case but normally you can always separate authentication and autorization. For example, you can apply security restrictions on controller level. Turn on security annotations and annotate your controllers with @Secured("ROLE_ACTION_1"), @Secured("ROLE_ACTION_2"), etc... Option number 2: you can declare your security restrictions in your security.xml using <security:intercept-url pattern="/action1.html" access="ROLE_ACTION_1" /> constructions. Have you tried?

Comment: Our application needs more granular control over authorization. Roles do not provide that, we need to check user rights on individual actions/objects.

Comment: May be you can consider ACl feature http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#domain-acls ? Or you can try emulate it via some custom filter http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-custom-filters. In any case there is a way to separate authorization from authentication, I am sure.

Comment: I think if you need more granular control of authorization, then you need to roll your own solution.  You can use Spring Security for the basic stuff, then have your own solution on top to check perms on objects ands stuff.  Or, just check everything.  You do not need to let Spring Security handle the authorization pieces at all, simply let it load up the user object and make sure its authenticated.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19900702/573389 ;  in a preauth scenario you can use that if you just want to show a 403