# Redirect to error page in spring security pre authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security and using Pre-Authentication module as my application is authenticated using Siteminder.

Following is the spring config XML

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

  <!-- http403EntryPoint -->

<security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
    <!-- Additional http configuration omitted -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="siteminderFilter" />
</security:http>

<bean id="siteminderFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="principalRequestHeader" value="SM_USER"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
        <bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"  class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
            <property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>   

<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.vzw.iaas.security.service.CustomUserDetailsService"></bean>
<bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"></bean>

<bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
 class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
 class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/NotAuthorized.html"/>
</bean>

<bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
 class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
    <property name="errorPage" value="/accessDenied.html"/>
</bean>
```

Now when there is an exception i.e. when I am sending a request to the application without sending a SM_USER the appliaction instead of showing the error page i.e. in that case NotAuthorized.html throws and internal server 500 error.

I would like to show my custom error pages in following scenarios.
1. When there is an AuthenticationException
2. When the user has no access.

Can Spring Security masters tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: Can someone please help me out here!!!

Comment: Can Spring Security master answer my question?

Comment: Folks help me out in this

Answer (score 2):

Make the exceptionIfHeaderMissing flag as false. Instead of throwing the error, the request will be handled using http403EntryPoint.

```
<bean id="siteminderFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="principalRequestHeader" value="SM_USER"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="exceptionIfHeaderMissing" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Comment: This fits just right.  It's good for things like /api/xyz endpoints where you just want to return an http 403 instead of, for example, redirecting to a login page.